# How many times is $f^{-1}$ differentbable if $f$ is differentiable $m$ times at $x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be continuously differentiable $m$ times at $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Does it then follow that $f^{-1}$ (assuming it exists) is also continuously differentiable $m$ times at $f(x)$? This is true for $m=1$ but does it hold for any $m$? Thank you!

Comment: For all the counterexamples, an answer providing a sufficient condition would be nice!

Comment: The answer is “yes” if $f'(x) \ne 0$: [On derivatives of the inverse of a real function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3870623/on-derivatives-of-the-inverse-of-a-real-function).

Comment: Teresa Lisbon: Go ahead, provide one. The counterexamples are important, as they point out where the mistake is. The author of the post (or you, if you feel like it) can then fix that mistake, and possibly find a positive result.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

What about $f(x)=x^3$ and $m=1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not true for $m=1$.
$f(x)=x^3$ is infinitely many times differentiable at 0, and its inverse function $\sqrt[3] x$ is not differentiable at 0. There can be a problem with zero derivatives.